# PHP OOP about class

Tags: php, oop

Hi I want to make a code like this... Can you give me an example on how to implement this?

```
$theclassvariable = new Myclass();
$theclassvariable->firstMethod()->secondMethod($param,$param);
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: you should learn concept of OOPs see this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_object_oriented.htm

Comment: Look up "fluent interface", but basically you need your `firstMethod()` to return `$this`

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You want to learn how to deal with **classes**? How to use them? Or maybe, how to call several methods at the same line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called chainable methods. In order to apply a method on $theclassvariable it needs to be an instance of a class. Let's define it:

```
class myClass {

    public function __construct()
    {
      echo 'a new instance has been created!<br />';
    }

    public function firstMethod()
    {
      echo 'hey there that\'s the first method!<br />';
      return $this;
    }

    public function secondMethod($first, $second)
    {
      echo $first + $second;
      return $this;
    }
}

$theclassvariable = new myClass();
```

If you want to apply a method on another method `$theclassvariable->firstMethod->secondMethod()`, `$theclassvariable->->firstMethod` needs to be an object too. In order to do that you need to return `$this` (the object) in each method. That's how you create chainable methods in PHP (and other languages...).

```
$theclassvariable->firstMethod()->secondMethod(1, 1);
```

The above will echo:

```
a new instance has been created!
hey there that's the first method!
2
```

Comment: How about if i want to chain other method from other Class?is it possible?ex:  $myclassvariable->firstmenthod()->secondmethodfromotherclass();

Comment: if you want to apply methods to a *something*, this *something* has to be an instance of the class in which the method has been defined

Answer (score 2):

Have the functions inside the class return the instance of the class

```
class Foo{

    public function a(){
        // Do Stuff
        return $this;
    }

    public function b(){
        // Do Stuff
        return $this;
    }

}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->a()->b();
```